# Zeromq in ROS as external library

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to use zeromq in ros as external library to communicate with other device(no `ros` on this device).

For testing i wrote `a rosnode with zeromq reciever`  and `zeromq sender` with [zeromq](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Ask-and-Ye-Shall-Receive)  sample code and ran both on my pc .

i am using port `tcp://10.64.7.220:9000`

If i  start rosnode  first, zeromq sender not able to connect with and exits with below error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'
  what():  Address already in use
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If i  start zeromq sender first,  rosnode not able to connect with and exits with error at

```
zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://10.64.7.220:9000");
```

I went through [ros networking little](http://roscon.ros.org/2013/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Networking-for-ROS-Users.pdf) but i couldn't figure it out why its not working.

thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173936/zeromq-in-ros-as-external-library/) by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3034 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was working well now, mistake was i was using trying to bind from both  `rosnode with zeromq reciever` and `zeromq sender` i.e zmq_bind() causing problem.  I modified as per sample code in zeromq and its working well.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0